# Write/read into/from file mode ios::binary when object has char* variable

Tags: c++, file, oop, binary

I have class Employee
Employee.h

```
class Employee
{
protected:
    char* name;//...another attributes..
public:
    Employee();...
}
```

Employee.cpp

```
Employee::Employee(){
   name = new char[100]();
}
```

with fout("data.txt",ios::out) (ofstream), when I use

```
fout.write((char*)employee1, sizoef(employee1));
```

Same with fin("data.txt",ios::in) (ifstream after fout above), I read

```
fin.read((char*)&employee2, sizeof(employee2));
```

Problem here employee1.name and employee2 have same address!! So when employee1.~Employee() executed, we can't use file data.txt to fin.read() (this address had removed).
So how can we write into file ios::binary to can read after this destructor executed? (I have tried using name[100] instead of name* and it work, but now I want use name* and declare char100 in constructor, can we?)

Comment: You can't write pointer values to a file and read them back expecting them to work. When you do that you're not writing the data they point to into the file at all. You need to properly serialize your data like writing an int for the length and then the actual string data. You could also use a fixed length array since you're always allocating 100 characters. This does mean that each record in the file will be the same length whether you use 5 characters or the array or 99.